# How to prevent a Windows 7 PC from sleeping when CPU usage is over X%?

Tags: windows-7, sleep, power-management, standby

I often leave the PC running into the night to process video files, so it shouldn't sleep while it's working but it would be nice if it went into sleep when it's done.

During the export the CPU is always above a set %, and when idle it's typically in the single digits.

Is there some tool or setting that would prevent the PC from going to sleep *as long as* the CPU usage (let's say averaged over one minute) stays above a specified limit?

Comment: The program may do it for you, Handbrake does it, and if you're not using it you probably should check it out.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried Manage PC shutdown. 
http://www.windows7download.com/win7-manage-pc-shutdown/pvgxwwgj.html

Comment: I don't think this will help unless the process stops, but most would just give a result.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set a specific limit on the number of cycles, but a Windows Task scheduler job that runs `shutdown -t 0` with "Only start the task if the computer is idle for _ minutes" specified should work.

Comment: Incorrect, you can, furthermore "idle for _ minutes" will not work if the program doesn't have built-in support.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest NoSleep:
http://www.computerbase.de/forum/showthread.php?t=770730

You need to enable the standby as usual and NoSleep suppress it if necessary. It seems that it is not available in English by now, but I think its easy to understand:
[image]